# Filling the inputs of SecurityAgent if they exist?

Tags: applescript, automator, keychain

I am trying to automate the export of my keychains (system and user), and while my script works if I remove the set values, it does not after adding them.

The error I am receiving is

```
System Events got an error: Can’t get text field 1 of group 1 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent". Invalid index.
```

It seems that I am asking for something that doesn't exist? Here is the modal

[image: System Events]

And here is the code.

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat while exists (processes where name is "SecurityAgent")
        tell process "SecurityAgent"
            set value of text field 1 of group 1 of window 1 to "adminuser"
            set value of text field 2 of group 1 of window 1 to "adminpass"
            click button "Allow" of group 1 of window 1
        end tell
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
end tell
```

If possible I would like to detect if there are fields prior to attempting to set so this can work with or without password prompting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked

```
set appName to "username"
set appPass to "password"

tell application "System Events"
    repeat while exists (processes where name is "SecurityAgent")
        tell process "SecurityAgent"
            if exists (text field 1 of window 1) then
                set value of text field 1 of window 1 to appName
                set value of text field 2 of window 1 to appPass
            end if
            click button "Allow" of group 1 of window 1
        end tell
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Nice, out of interest what do you use it for? since that screen comes up rarely.

Comment: I was dumping the system keychain via: `security dump-keychain -d /Library/Keychains/System.keychain > keychain-system.txt`

Comment: @Buscar웃 here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/ehime/9c518f405315dc3087c3

Comment: I received the following error in 10.14.5 Mojave: `execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get every process of process "<Process>" whose name = "SecurityAgent". (-1728)`. A workaround is to translate the `if conditional then body end if` to `try conditional on error body end try`, as the error implies the existence of `SecurityAgent`.